# entering and getting values from arrays in one ConcurrentDictionary with C#

Tags: c#, get, enter, concurrentdictionary

Up to this moment I was using **simple arrays** to enter and get necessary information.

the first example is following:

```
            // ===Example 1. Enter info ////
            string[] testArr1 = null;
            testArr1[0] = "ab";
            testArr1[1] = "2";
            // ===Example 1. GET info ////
            string teeext = testArr1[0];
            // =======================
```

and the second example:

```
            // ====== Example 2. Enter info ////
            string[][] testArr2 = null;
            List<int> listTest = new List<int>();
            listTest.Add(1);
            listTest.Add(3);
            listTest.Add(7);
            foreach (int listitem in listTest)
            {
                testArr2[listitem][0] = "yohoho";
            }
            // ====== Example 2. Get info ////
            string teeext2 = testArr2[0][0];
            // =======================
```

But right now I'm trying to **assign an identification number** to each array, so I could **identify multiple different arrays** in one ConcurrentDictionary.

**How do you Enter and Get info out of array in dictionary?**

Look, we have two identifiers and two dictionaries:

```
            decimal identifier1 = 254;
            decimal identifier2 = 110;
            ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, string[]> test1 = new ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, string[]>();
            ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, string[][]> test2 = new ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, string[][]>();
```

I was imagining something like this:

```
//////////Example 1
//To write info
test1.TryAdd(identifier1)[0] = "a";
test1.TryAdd(identifier1)[1] = "b11";

test1.TryAdd(identifier2)[0] = "152";
//to get info
string value1 = test1.TryGetValue(identifier1)[0];
string value1 = test1.TryGetValue(identifier2)[0];

//////////Example 2
//To write info: no idea
//to get info: no idea
```

P.S.: The code above doesn't work (since it's self-made).. so what's the right way to enter information into string[] and string[][] in ConcurrentDictionary by an ID? (and to get it out)

Comment: I'm confused. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: "I'm trying to assign an identification number to each array, so I could identify different arrays within ConcurrentDictionary"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your declarations

```
decimal identifier1 = 254;
decimal identifier2 = 110;
ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, string[]> test1 = new ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, string[]>();
ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, string[][]> test2 = new ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, string[][]>();
```

you can use code like this

```
  test1[identifier1] = new string[123];
  test1[identifier1][12] = "hello";

  test2[identifier2] = new string[10][];
  test2[identifier2][0] = new string[20];
  test2[identifier2][0][1] = "world";
```

to enter your data. Here's an example of accessing the data you entered:

```
  Console.WriteLine(test1[identifier1][12] + " " + test2[identifier2][0][1]);
```

I must say, though, that such code tends to be quite convoluted and difficult to debug, especially for the test2 case. Are you sure you want to use jagged arrays?

Comment: well, I need to store data somewhere.. the choice was between INI files, SQl database and ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: Writing values like this isn't threadsafe though so why use ConcurrentDictionary?